# How do I configure SSL on Nginx and Unicorn for Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, unicorn

I am trying to add SLL to my rails app. For that, I am using [certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuother-nginx). Till now I have gone through these articles [link 1](https://gorails.com/guides/free-ssl-with-rails-and-nginx-using-let-s-encrypt) and [link 2](https://afterthoughtsoftware.com/posts/lets-encrypt-nginx-and-ruby-on-rails). But both are not working. Let me know what is the issue.

As when deploying using nginx and unicorn, no .conf file is generated. My configuration is given below

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

upstream app {
    # Path to Unicorn SOCK file, as defined previously
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/railsApp/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /home/ubuntu/railsApp/public;
    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
    location @app {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/opoll.xyz/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/opoll.xyz/privkey.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout 5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_dhparam /home/deploy/dhparams.pem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this conf file to site-enabled folder by using this code

```
sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo service nginx restart
```